# When is a Static preferred over Dynamic Named Sets in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

Ok, so this question is with regard to the use of Dynamic and Static Sets in Analysis Server. It is my understanding that Static Sets are evaluated during the processing of the Cube and don't regard any conditions specified in the WHERE slicer in MDX. Whereas Dynamic Sets are evaluated during the time of Query execution.

I have a cube that has an extremely large number of customer Claim numbers in a Dimension. If my clients wanted to view any number of Measures associated with these Claim Numbers but wanted to look at a range, they'd have to filter a good number of the Claim Numbers.

To alleviate this, I created a Dynamic Set that does nothing more than group several thousand of the numbers into a group that they may use. The problem is that I've seen a great degradation of performance using the Dynamic Sets so I am thinking that a Static Set may suffice for this type of scenario.

So will a Static Set suffice if it is just a set of Dimension members with no calculations contained in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least static sets gives SSAS the ability to cache results; so you might get some performance improvement but rethinking the [Claim] dimension would be better if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the response and recommendation Marc. I will accept it as an answer. Unfortunately, that Dimension is about as simple as it can get based on the client's requirements. There is no Hierarchy to it, just a massive amount of numbers which they want to have the ability to query against. Your input is greatly appreciated.